# Draw a line between two data points from separate variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect the data points from highlight2 to their corresponding highlight3 data points

```
ggplot() + theme_classic() +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5), breaks = c(seq(0,5,1))) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50,100), breaks = c(seq(-50,100,50))) +
geom_point(data=highlight2,aes(x=A,y=B),color='red', size=4) +
geom_point(data=highlight3,aes(x=A,y=B),color='blue', size=4) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 16, face="bold"))
```

Here is the plot so far. I basically want to connect the red dots to their corresponding blue dots on the plot.

[image]

Comment: Please include your data in the question: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example? in particular the sections: "Producing a minimal dataset" and "Copy your data". ideally provide your data in the form df <- data.frame(...) where "..." are your variables and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included your data, so I've had to make some up. Essentially, you need to use `geom_segment` to join the points, which means you need to combine your two data frames into one. You can use `dplyr` to do this. Note that your call to `ggplot` is just the same as the one in your question except I have added in the `geom_segment` line.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Dummy data
set.seed(68)
highlight2 <- data.frame(A = runif(9, 0, 4), B = rnorm(9, 20, 30))
highlight3 <- data.frame(A = runif(9, 0, 4), B = rnorm(9, 20, 30))

# OP's plot
ggplot() + theme_classic() +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5), breaks = c(seq(0,5,1))) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50,100), breaks = c(seq(-50,100,50))) +
geom_point(data=highlight2,aes(x=A,y=B),color='red', size=4) +
geom_point(data=highlight3,aes(x=A,y=B),color='blue', size=4) +
theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 16, face="bold")) + 
# New bit
geom_segment(data = highlight2 %>% 
                    mutate(x2 = highlight3$A, y2 = highlight3$B),
             aes(x = A, y = B, xend = x2, yend = y2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>